# Resize blocks of linux filesystem

Tags: command-line, server, partitioning, hard-drive

I use UbuntuServer on an Dedicated Server in Version 21.04 and just resized my HDD in the HyperViser.
But now I can't change the blocksize of the sda2 (my Linux Filesystem).
I tried few diffrent things but nearly everything get's the same error.

For example:

```
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda2
resize2fs 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)
The filesystem is already 16776448 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Furthermore here are the blocks sizes of the sda, sda1 and 2.

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
 8       0  268435456 sda
 8       1       1024 sda1
 8       2   67105792 sda2
```

Y'all would be awesome if you could give me any hint where I wen't wrong.

Comment: 1st try to reboot the server, and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you resized your *disk* from the outside (on the host system); that's the first step.

As the next step, you need to resize the *partition* that your filesystem is on. The filesystem can only grow as large as the partition that it's on; that's what that message tells you.

You can use the `resizepart` sub-command of `parted`. See also
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169395/how-do-i-resize-partitions-and-filesystems-on-them

When you are done with that, you can use that `resize2fs` command.

Comment: Thank you very much, that help me a lot :)